# AdMob banner shows in Simulator but not on device/TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, testflight

I'm using AdMob for banner ads in an app.  The banner ads show up on the Simulator but not when I run it on an iPhone device via connected cord or TestFlight.

This is my code for running it on a real device:

```
let request = GADRequest()
bannerView.adUnitID = realAdUnitID
bannerView.rootViewController = self
bannerView.delegate = self
bannerView.load(request)
```

Am I missing something?

*I've tried to look at other questions but nothing has worked for me yet that has been suggested.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, do you running the **debug** or the **release** version? If you run your app in the debug mode, add the device id (you can find it in the console) to the `testDevices` array:

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID,  // All simulators
                       "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"];  // Sample device ID
```

[Read more about test ads in AdMob Documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads)

And the second thing you should consider, that AdMob may not provide enough fill rate for your ads. Especially if the app is new, it can take some time while traffic will be analysed, before the service will provide your some ads. Consider this, if your testing your app in release mode.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! So I got the banner ads showing on the simulator using `request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]` but I'm trying to get the banner ads showing on TestFlight and was assuming I wouldn't need to manually put in each Device ID for each TestFlight user in the big test group.  Is that an incorrect assumption then?

Comment: @SRMR, yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Ah, thats too bad. So then once the app is ready for App Store, just remove the `request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]` line and everything will work fine?

Comment: @SRMR, you can even try it right now, just don't click on ads too much. I did so, and I AdMob didn't blocked my app.

Comment: So you're saying that you can leave `request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]` in even on the production / App Store version and everything is fine huh?

Comment: No, not at all. I want to say that you can remove `testDevices` and run scheme with release build configuration to test the ads without submitting to Appstore.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try checking your iPhone Settings to see if Limit Ad Tracking is turned on?
(Settings/Privacy/Advertising).